# Find linearity in a graph

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am doing automation for a project and the results I get is in the form of a graph wherein I take the performance results.

Now the performance results which I take is generally at a straight line from the graph.

For example lets say the results from the graph in a List could be like this:
10, 30,90,100, 150,200,250,300,350,400,450,800,1000,1500,2000,2010,2006,2004,2000,1900,1800,1700, 1600,1000,500,400,0.

As you see the performance of the device starts increasing and then at a certain point it remains linear and with failures it starts dropping.

The point I want to take is the linear line.

As you can see in the list of numbers we see that from (2000,2010,2006,2004,2000) there is some kind of a linear line.

I am not asking for any code or Algorithm to solve this....I do not need an answer. If anyone can just give me a hint or a little clue I will try to do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean constant or linear? 
If you mean linear:
Why not take the differences of adjacent values and search for a sequence that stays close to constant?
If you mean constant:
Why not take the differences of adjacent values and search for a sequence that stays close to 0?

Comment: Brilliant !. Ill use this.

Answer (score 1):

First decide on the absolute or relative tolerance you can handle, that decides what is a straight line.

Then iterate trough the array checking the value of a point with the next point, if they are within tolerance, continue iterating until you get a point that is not and store those points. They represent a straight line.

This solution is very simple, not perfect and takes O(n) time.

Comment: Thanks you !. Yes the time is not a concern since this is an automation project.